# Silly question about partitions and equivalence classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a non-empty set and $E$ an quivalence relation on $X$. Given $x \in X$, Let

$$ \mathscr{E} = \{ [x] : x \in X \} $$

be the collection of all equivalence classes $[x] = \{ y : y E x \}$ of $x$ under $E$.

#### Homework exercise

Show that $\mathscr{E}$ form a partition of $X$.

#### Attempt

I have already proved that if $[x],[y] \in \mathscr{E}$, and if $[x] \neq [y] $, then $[x] \cap [y] = \varnothing$. It remains to show, according to the definition that $\bigcup_{[x] \in \mathscr{E}} [x] = X $ and that $\varnothing \notin \mathscr{E} $.

We already know that since $X$ is the ambient set we have that the union is in $X$, so we show only that $X$ is contained in the union. Let $x \in X$. We have that $x \in [x] \subset \bigcup_{[x] \in \mathscr{E} } [x] $ and hence we got it.

Finally, I am kind of confused how can I show that $\varnothing \notin \mathscr{E}$. I am kind of confused with the definition of partition. Why do we require the empty set to be out of the collection. Isnt the empty set in all sets ? I hope someone can explain this to me. Thanks

Comment: The empty set is a subset but not an element of the set of partitions. Reason: every element of the partition can be characterised by one element of X. No element belongs to the empty set...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partition of a set is formed by grouping of the set's elements into subsets in such a way that every element is included in one and only one of the subsets.

Why do we exclude the empty set from being one of the subsets in a partition?   Because none of the subsets formed by so grouping elements can be empty.

And that's how you show that the empty set is not a member of the set of equivalence classes of $X$; by showing that all equivalence class of $X$ must contain at least one element of $X$.

---

Hint: equivalence relations are reflexive.